# python3 zipfile in botocore while uploading in AWS Lambda

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, zip

Piece of code works well in python2.7 while porting this to python3.6 the zipfile throws errors.

```
    file_name = 'lambda-package3.zip'
with ZipFile(file_name, 'w') as myzip:
    myzip.write('__init__.py')
    myzip.write('mymain.py')
    myzip.write('resources/lex_handler.py')
    myzip.write('resources/myhelper.py')
```

defined a botcontrol function for uploading in AWS Lamba and when I try to read this ZipFile using

```
  "Code": {"ZipFile": open("lambda-package3.zip", "r")}
```

I get the following error

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not '_io.TextIOWrapper'
```

when I run the same in python2.7, it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `open("lambda-package3.zip", "rb")`.

Comment: I did but getting the error `code` TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not '_io.BufferedReader' `code`

Comment: Can you share more code then? What's botcontrol? How does the `"Code": {"ZipFile" ...` fit into the picture? Where is it executed?

Comment: I am working on a project to create conversational bots using AWS Lex. Complete app from scratch is built in Python and uploaded as a package in AWS Lex using AWS CLI commands. The uploaded package will be in a zip file. Some sample code

Comment: complete zip file code           
`botcontrol_function = {
    "Code": {"ZipFile": open("lambda-package3.zip", "rb")},
    "Description": "MyChatbot, Voice Power",
    "FunctionName": "{}".format(FUNCTION_NAME),
    "Handler": "mymain.lambda_handler",
    "MemorySize": 128,
    "Role": "arn:aws:iam::{}:role/myvoicechatbot-role".format(ACCOUNT_ID),
    "Runtime": "python3.6",
    "Timeout": 10,
    "TracingConfig": {"Mode": "PassThrough"},
    "Publish": True,
}`